# Rails - extract substring with in [ and ] from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, string, substring

This works.

```
"<name> <substring>"[/.*<([^>]*)/,1]
=> "substring"
```

But I want to extract substring within `[` and `]`.

**input**:

```
string = "123 [asd]"
```

**output**:

```
asd
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
"123 [asd]"[/\[(.*?)\]/, 1]
```

will return

```
"asd"
```

You can test it here:
https://rextester.com/YGZEA91495

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few more ways to extract the desired string.

```
str = "123 [asd] 456"
```

**#1**

```
r = /
    (?<=\[)  # match '[' in a positive lookbehind
    [^\]]*   # match 1+ characters other than ']'
    (?=\])   # match ']' in a positive lookahead
    /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode

str[r]
  #=> "asd"
```

**#2**

```
r = /
    \[       # match '['
    [^\]]*   # match 1+ characters other than ']'
    \]       # match ']'
    /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode

str[r][1..-2]
  #=> "asd"
```

**#3**

```
r = /
    .*\[     # match 0+ characters other than a newline, then '['
    |        # or
    \].*     # match ']' then 0+ characters other than a newline
    /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode

str.gsub(r, '')
  #=> "asd"
```

**#4**

```
n = str.index('[')
  #=> 4
m = str.index(']', n+1)
  #=> 8
str[n+1..m-1]
  #=> "asd"
```

See [String#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-index).